# Losing formatting when copying from excel to powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a table in Powerpoint in a formatting that I like:
[image]

And an excel worksheet with updated values:

[image]

And **all** I want to do is to copy-paste these excel values into the powerpoint table, while keeping the formatting of the powerpoint table. It always looks like this, with boldness, font, fontcolor, fontsize, row height, ... changed:

[image]

Curiously, the cell shading does not change.

**Does anyone know how to keep all formatting?**

Office 365 btw.

---

What I've tried:

- Selecting a single cell, or the entire table, before pasting.
- All paste-options that are offered in the context menu: [image]
- Applying the format-painter. It seems to only copy the formatting of a single table cell, not the entire table.

Software that's used by millions and millions of people every day surely can't be that bad, right? Right?

Answer (score 0):

Have a go at a linked file or table. In theory once you have linked to the file, you can change formatting in PPT and when it refreshes, it will only be the data that gets refresh.

Have a look at this link
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-excel-data-in-powerpoint-0690708a-5ce6-41b4-923f-11d57554138d#OfficeVersion=Newer_versions